# Adding startup script (init.py and menu.py) to Nuke path with sitecustomize

Tags: python, nuke

I'm trying to point to a startup script location in Nuke instead of using the default one (`%USERPROFILE%/.nuke/*.py`). From [this page](https://learn.foundry.com/nuke/developers/63/pythondevguide/startup.html), either commands with the `nuke` module, or adding to the path are said to be valid options.

In my `sitecustomize.py`, if I run `import nuke`, I get the message `Error: global root initialised more than once`, and Nuke will not launch. I believe it could be something to do with the inbuilt `_pathsetup.py`, which looks like it runs during startup to correctly set the environment for the moudle.

I also tried adding to the `NUKE_PATH` environment variable, but Nuke just overwrites that before it's properly launched.

Does anyone have any idea how I could add a folder containing `init.py` and `menu.py` to the startup path, without specifially editing anything in documents or program files?

I'm currently writing `nuke.pluginAppendPath` to `%USERPROFILE%/.nuke/init.py` each time Nuke is launched, but obviously that's not very pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a good idea to use some conditional expressions in standard init.py file. Like

```
if nukeverion=12: exec(config2.py)
```